# How to receive data from ESP8266 Wifi Module using php

Tags: php, arduino, wifi, esp8266

I tried with sending a GET request using ESP8266 wifi module using Arduino.The module successfully responded with :

> SEND OK +IPD

On server, I want to receive the data and write it in a text file. So i tried the following codes

```
>parse_str( html_entity_decode( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) , $out); $data= $out['data'];

$fileStatus=file_put_contents('myFile.txt',$data,FILE_APPEND);
if($fileStatus!=false){
    echo "SUCCESS";
} else{ echo "FAIL"; }
```

But the data failed to store.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your GET request from the ESP to the server was made to the URL http://example.com/myPhpScript.php?parameter1=xxxx&parameter2=yyyy

you should be able to get the the value of parameter1 and paramter2 like this:

```
<?php
$p1 = $_GET['parameter1'];
$p2 = $_GET['parameter2'];

$data = $p1.','.$p2;
file_put_contents('myFile.txt',$data,FILE_APPEND);
?>
```